# How can I install Ubuntu 13.04 on my USB stick and make it bootable to Windows 8?

Tags: boot, wubi, live-usb, windows-8

I used the instructions listed on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and I used a 4GB flash drive to try to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo P500 preinstalled with  Windows 8. I want to make a bootable USB stick but it won't work. I've read some stuff about SecureBoot and UEFI on Windows 8 computers but I want to make sure that absolutely every change I do to my computer in order to boot Ubuntu from my USB is reversible. I am completely new to Linux, but I want to try it out. All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How won't it work? At what stage do things go wrong and what errors do you receive? What have you done so far? +1 For having a go even though you're new, and good luck :)